# How to await a users response?

Tags: c#, discord.net

After asking a question in a channel

```
await channel.SendMessageAsync("question?");
```

how do I wait for a certain response? (eg. yes, no)
I've tried

```
string input;
bool done = false;
while(!done)
{
     input = channel.GetMessageAsync(channel.Id).ToString();
     if (String.Compare(input, "yes") == 0)
     {
          //code here
          done = true;
     }
     else if (String.Compare(input, "no") == 0)
     {
          //code here
          done = true;
     }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 input = channel.GetMessageAsync(channel.Id).ToString();
```

Makes no sense. `GetMessageAsync()` expects you to provider a messageID not an channel ID.

Now you don't know the ID from a message that has not been send yet, so instead of looping till infinity for a message may or may never follow. I would advice you to instead handle this in your message/Command handler.

Here you could keep track of a List, containing people who *triggered* your initial command. After which you can check if their message contained a Yes/No or maybe even something else all together.